# Running APT does not work: insserv: warning: script 'K20.depend.start' missing LSB tags and overrides

Tags: apt, dependencies

Whenever I install something I get one of two things

```
$ sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

will result in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package netflix-desktop'
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install -fy
```

will result in

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
apache2
cups-daemon
mysql-server-5.7
bluez
cups-core-drivers
cups
bluez-cups
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm sure that those particular applications are corrupted but I have no idea on how I should remove/replace/repair.

**EDIT**
This is the start of the full output - there's about 140k characters of

```
.depend.start
.depend.boot
.depend.stop
.depend.start
```

etc.etc.etc.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -fy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.4) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K20.depend.start' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K20.depend.boot' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K20.depend.stop' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service .depend.start and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service .depend.start if started
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting .depend.start depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .depend.boot depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .depend.stop depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting .depend.start depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```

Comment: Can you post the entire log when you run `sudo apt-get install -fy`? Or else, it is difficult for us to determin your problem.

Comment: the entire log is 140k characters, it basically repeats the last part for the entire way through - i've attached what comes up for the first few lines when i put  sudo apt-get install -fy through

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing, upgrading or autoremove: insserv warning: script 'K01runlcactivator' and 'runlcactivator'](//askubuntu.com/q/951658) see if this helps - also see link to post on [unix.se] in the answer (Reviewers: I can't vote because I unintentionally dropped my hammer and had to fix the tags - I don't want to hammer & the tags were wrong anyway)

Comment: this will surely help you, add the LSB comment in K20.depend.start (stop &boot) files path is `/etc/rc7.d` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289667/unable-to-install-anything-using-apt-get-because-of-insserv